store more tx_data
I find that my node has a very low amount of data, what parameters can I use to ensure that my node keeps a month's worth of data . And the version of solana-valicator is v1.18.15.

You can use the  --limit-ledger-size flag for this.
The help message gives more info:
        --limit-ledger-size <SHRED_COUNT>
            Keep this amount of shreds in root slots. [default: 10000]

Afaik there is 64 shreds per slot, and one slot every 400ms. This means if we want to store one month, we'd need:
1 month = 2678400000 Ms
= 6696000 slots
6696000 slots * 64 shreds/slot = 428544000 shreds.
So if you use --limit-ledger-size with that number, that should work out to about a month.
